# Using del operator removes list intellisense in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, del

I noticed that when defining a list in python in vscode, I get the expected type and method intellisense, like this:

[image]

But after using the `del` operator on the list, the intellisense seems to disappear:

[image: No intellisense here]

I haven't noticed this with other list methods (`pop`, `insert` etc).  Is this a bug with python in vscode, or does the `del` operator fundamentally alter the list in a way that vscode can no longer offer intellisense?

I am using VSCode 1.53.2 on OSX Cataline 10.15.6, with the official microsoft [python vscode extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python), version 2021.2.636928669.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:  The "Python" language service used by VS Code by default is "Jedi". Its "intellisense" here is affected. Therefore, please use "Microsoft" or "Pylance" language service. `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` or  `"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",`

The results of my test in VS Code show that no matter whether "del" is used, "intellisense" can be used:

Without "del":

[image]

"del" is used:

[image]

Since the "intellisense" function of python in VS Code is provided by the Python extension, it is recommended that you reinstall it. If it still doesn't work, please try to disable other `VS Code extensions that are not in use` to avoid mutual influence. (Please click "`Enable`" to restore the disabled extension and it will restore the previous use.)

Reference: [IntelliSense for python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense).

Comment: I am primarily a typescript developer at this point and I have a handful of extensions that I really need.  I don't know if a solution that involves disabling all other extensions is really a great option...but thank you for your time and your thoughtful response

Comment: @Seth Lutske -Yes, normally the extensions in VS Code can be used together well, but sometimes there are some extensions that affect each other. so the disabling of other extensions is just a suggestion and I modified my expression.  Has this problem been resolved?

Comment: Unforunately no, this did not work for me.  I disabled all extensions except python and jupyter, reloaded vscode, but no change

Comment: Wow...I cannot tell you how much I regret disabling all extensions.  Even though I only did it for the workspace I was working in, and I reversed it by reenabling extensions one by one, it seems to have broken my git gutter highlighting as well as my prettier autoformatting, in all my workspaces.  What a headache.

Comment: @Seth Lutske  -Please "enable" the extensions you need, and the use of VS Code will resume. In addition to using the "Python" extension and the "Jupyter" extension, language services also need to be used
"Microsoft" or "Pylance", the default language service used by VS Code is "Jedi", and its "intellisense" here is affected.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try your new idea - switching to pylance.  That did it for me.  Thank you!